# How to stop CasperJS execution and let the user input some value and then continue to execute?

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs, captcha, casperjs

I'm using *PhantomJS* and *CasperJS* to automate some of my tasks. In one of the task, I need to manually provide captcha strings before I can actually work on the task. For this problem, what I can think of is to capture a screenshot of the web page, then manually check the captured image and save the captcha string into a text file. After that I can use the *file system* module in *CasperJS* to read that value and continue to do the process. I want to know what's the best way to do this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of the stuctured manner/control flow of CasperJS compared to PhantomJS, such a task is not easy.

### 1. Pull approach (file polling)

Let's say there is a secondary program (type 1) which handles showing the CAPTCHA, receiving the input and writing a text file with the CAPTCHA input. All that CasperJS can handle is to write the CAPTCHA screenshot to disk and wait for the file with the "parsed" text.

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    captchaFile = "cfile.png",
    parsedFile = "pfile.txt";
casper.waitForCaptcha = function(captchaFile, parsedFile){
    casper.then(function(){
        this.captureSelector(captchaFile, "someSelectorOfTheCaptcha");
    });
    casper.waitFor(function check(){
        return fs.exists(parsedFile);
    }, function then(){
        // do something on time
        // check if correct...
        if (!correct) {
            fs.remove(captchaFile);
            fs.remove(parsedFile);
            this.waitForCaptcha(captchaFile, parsedFile);
            // Problem: the secondary process needs to sense that a new CAPTCHA is presented
        }
    }, function onTimeout(){
        // do something when failed
    }, 60000); // 1min should suffice as a timeout
    return this;
};
casper.start(url).waitForCaptcha(captchaFile, parsedFile).run();
```

This code assumes that you want to retry when the CAPTCHA was wrong, but not if the minute deliberately passed without the decoded file. This is a pull process by polling if files are already there.

### 2. Push approach

A push process is also possible where the secondary program (type 2) sends requests to the CasperJS process by utilizing the [PhantomJS webserver module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/). Because there will be two concurrent control flows, the CasperJS part needs to wait a long time, but as soon as a request is received with the decoded words the waiting can be broken with [`unwait`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#unwait).

```
var server = require('webserver').create(),
    fs = require("fs"),
    captchaFile = "cfile.png";

function neverendingWait(){
    this.wait(5000, neverendingWait);
}

casper.checkCaptcha = function(captchaFile, phantomPort, secondaryPort){
    // here the CAPTCHA is saved to disk but it can also be set directly if captured through casper.captureBase64
    this.captureSelector(captchaFile, "someSelectorOfTheCaptcha");

    // send request to the secondary program from the page context
    this.evaluate(function(file){
        __utils__.sendAJAX("http://localhost:"+secondaryPort+"/", "POST", {file: file}, true);
    }, captchaFile);

    // start the server to receive solved CAPTCHAs
    server.listen(phantomPort, {
       'keepAlive': true
    }, function (request, response) {
        console.log('Request received at ' + new Date());
        if (request.post) { // is there a response?
            this.then(function(){
                // check if it is correct by reading request.post ...
                if (!correct){
                    response.statusCode = 404;
                    response.headers = {
                        'Cache': 'no-cache',
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
                    };
                    response.close();
                    server.close();
                    this.checkCaptcha(captchaFile, phantomPort, secondaryPort);
                } else {
                    response.statusCode = 200;
                    response.headers = {
                        'Cache': 'no-cache',
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
                    };
                    response.close();
                    server.close();
                    this.unwait(); // abort the neverendingWait
                }
            });
        } else {
            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.headers = {
              'Cache': 'no-cache',
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
            };
            response.close();
            server.close();
            this.checkCaptcha(captchaFile, phantomPort, secondaryPort);
        }
    });
    return this;
};

casper.start(url).then(function(){
    this.checkCaptcha(captchaFile, 8080, 8081);
}).then(neverendingWait).then(function(){
    // Do something here when the captcha is successful
}).run();
```

Comment: @Yousui If you're interested, I can try to flesh out the push approach, but I never actually used the webserver module let alone with CasperJS.

Comment: Yes Artjom. If you can provide a skeleton that will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I added some code for the push approach, but I didn't try it. It should work though.